# knockout utils function - jsfiddle

Tags: knockout.js

https://jsfiddle.net/3y3ucxpr/

I am trying filter new cars.

```
newHondaCars : ko.pureComputed(function(){
             return ko.utils.arrayFilter(hondaCars, function (car) {
           return car.year > 2010; 
  });
 })
```

What is wrong from the above fiddle? I can't populate select list.

Answer (score 0):

First of all never forget to check your browser's `console` log whenever you write a `Javascript` code.

`hondaCars` object is a part of `vm` object that you are binding,so the `pureComputed` function does not know anything about `hondaCars`.You have to pass `hondaCars` from `vm` object.

`return ko.utils.arrayFilter(vm.hondaCars, function (car)`.

**Note:**
I highly recommend you to implement your model in a way that you can keep track of `this` reference.Also in future if you need to have multiple sub-models then you won't have any problem plus it would be much easier to debug when your code gets bigger.

https://jsfiddle.net/3y3ucxpr/3/

**JS:**

```
  var hondaCars =  [
            { name: 'Civic', id: 1, year: 2007},
            { name: 'Pilot', id: 2, year: 2015},
            { name: 'CRV', id: 3, year: 2014},
            { name: 'Odyssey', id: 4, year: 2016}
        ];
    var mainViewModel = function () {
         // this way you keep the reference `this` for this model seperate 
        var self = this;     
        self.selectedCar = ko.observable(),
        self.newHondaCars = ko.pureComputed(function(){
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(hondaCars, function (car) {
               return car.year > 2010; 
            });
         })
    };
    // create a new instance of your model and 
    var vm = new mainViewModel()
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the format you already have, you can just delete the newHondaCars function and add a function just before ko.applyBindings(vm):

```
vm.AddItems = ko.computed(function(){
     return ko.utils.arrayFilter(vm.hondaCars(), function (item) {return (item.year > 2010); })
});
```

Then on the html you should use this:

```
options: $root.AddItems,
```

Instead of:

```
options: newHondaCars(),
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3y3ucxpr/4/

I hope this was helpful.

Other useful links:

- http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/ewlll/
- http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html
- http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html